# Windows 10 can not create files on the desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am using Windows 10, my user has administrator privileges, but there's also another admin user.

When creating a folder on the desktop I have this response:

> "Path not found C:/users/myuser"

In addition to this I can't create files manually in the folder `C:/users/myuser/desktop`, because when I do so I get the following:

> "Path not found"

On desktop I have `"read only" = true`, but when I change the value to `False` and save, changes are not saved. How I can troubleshoot this problem? Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Hi Olek, Does your user have the same permissions as the other Admin? This looks to me like a ownership/access problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems creating files by admin user:
I was investigating the problem for a while. Turns out Windows 10 has new type of protection - called "Controlled folder access".
This kind of protection enables to block modification of Controlled folders - by default - they include "Desktop", "Documents&Settings" and etc. When the mode turned on - event admin can not create/modify files inside folders. This is strange.
So in order to fix this - just turn off "Controlled folder access". It can be found in

`"Windows defender Security Center" -> "Virus & threat protection" -> "Virus & threat protection setting"`

Comment: Controlled folder access isn’t enabled by default but the folders are protected by default if it’s enabled